# salesforce apex callback function onclick of logout in force.com site

Tags: force.com

Below is my logout code . I want to call a function where I can perform some operation once the code for logout for user is executed for force.com site.

```
 PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/default/secur/logout.jsp');

 pageRef.setRedirect(true);

 return pageRef;
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you cannot do anything after log out .You can write a method and perform all logic and finally return to logout call.

Comment: @Mohith, I recommend you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do anything after log out .You can write a method and perform all logic and finally return to logout call.

```
public pagereference logout(){
   //perform Business logic here
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/default/secur/logout.jsp');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```